# How to assign PHP variables from foreach loop output?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, loops, foreach

I have a foreach loop which prints out the usernames of all entries in a database table like so:

```
foreach($results as $result){

echo $result->username;
echo '<br>';

}
```

As more and more users are added to the table, the list will grow.  I would like to take the complete list and assign each entry to a separate PHP variable for use later on the PHP script.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You mean like $results[0], $results[1], $results[2] and so on?

Comment: you have a list and it will grow. the best way to do this is with an array like you already have. why would you want to have separate vars for each?

Comment: no. you don't want a separate variable. Consider when you reach 50,000 users. Do you really want 50,000 separate variables? Hell no. You've already got them in a nice neat and clean array. Keep them there.

Comment: You are correct that I have them in an array, so I guess my mis-understanding has to do with how I can use those array values later in the script.  I am trying to apply each username as a javascript variable.  I was thinking that I would need to pull them out individual, but now with these comments I will reconsider this based upon the pre-existing array.  Thanks.

Comment: Will your javascript need access to every username in the table, or just a few? If just a few, you can consider using ajax to get a username. For example if you're checking to see if a username exists, you can write a script like "checkUsername.php" which queries the DB for a username (provided as a POST variable), and outputs "true" or "false". Then use ajax to post the username to checkUsername.php and check the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want individual variables, try an array:

```
foreach($results as $result){
    $names[] = $result->username;
}
```

In PHP 7 it's even easier:

```
$names = array_column($results, null, 'username');
```

Answer (score 0):

Put them in an array:

```
$names = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $names[] = $result->username;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments `I am trying to apply each username as a javascript variable`, all you need seems to be something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var usernames = <?php echo json_encode($results); ?>;
</script>
```

Of course if you only need one element from the `$results` array, you should first generate a reduced list using one of the other answers; if you use the whole `$results` array, all information in there will be sent to the browser / visible to the visitor.

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` loops are soooo out of fashion :p

```
$names = array_map(function($r) {return $r->username;},$results);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want too.... 
but you could do ...

```
foreach($results as $result)
{
    $$result->username = $result;
 }
```

That answers your question. But why anyone would do that is beyond me

Answer (score -1):

I use below code

```
<?php

$string = 'a|b|c|d|e|f';

$tags = explode('|' , $string);


foreach($tags as $i =>$key) {
$i >0;
     $a[$i]=$key .'</br>';

}

echo $a[3];
```

good luck